# Запуск jar на терминал

Tags: java, linux, jar

Такая проблема: были созданы сервер и клиент и каждый по-отдельности помещён в jar пакет. Как запустить сервер и клиент на терминале (Linux)? По отдельности не получается, пробовал через java -jar Server.jar запускается сервер и клиент уже не подключить. Если пишу вместо Server.jar Client.jar соответственно запускается клиент и сервер не отвечает. Как запустить их одновременно?

Comment: В смысле, не подключить? А как они общаются? Если у тебя сервер и клиент разделен, то они должны как-то общаться, например по rest и запускать их должно быть можно по отдельности.

Comment: Поставить в конец команды `&`.

Comment: @Deepstack, консоль у него одна, а из неё надо параллельно запустить две программы.

Answer (score 1):

> Как запустить сервер и клиент на терминале (Linux)?

Запускайте в **двух** терминалах.

1. Открываем одно окно терминала
2. Запускаем в нём сервер
3. Открываем окно другого терминала
4. Запускаем в нём клиента

Есть ещё вариант запуска в окне одного терминала, одновременно, но он не очень удобный и приводиьт его здесь я не буду.